# Language-ext: How to combine synchronous call with async calls?

Tags: c#, language-ext

I'm struggling with the mix of sync. and async calls in language-ext.

I've the following simplified example:

```
void Main()
{
    var content = 
    Validate("https://www.google.com")
    .Bind(Transform)
    .Bind(FetchUriAsync);
}

private static Either<Error, string> Validate(string url)
{
    return url;
}


private static Either<Error, Uri> Transform(string uri)
{
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(uri);
    return uriBuilder.Uri;
}

private static async EitherAsync<Error,HttpContent> FetchUriAsync (Uri uri)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    
    return response.Content;
}
```

How can I bind FetchUriAsync to the previous calls?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want `content` to be an `EitherAsync<Error, HttpContent>`, you can use `ToAsync` to convert the `Either` to an `EitherAsync`, and then you can `Bind`.

```
var content = 
    Validate("https://www.google.com")
    .Bind(Transform)
    .ToAsync()
    .Bind(FetchUriAsync);
```

Also, your current implementation of `FetchUriAsync` doesn't compile, since `async` methods can't return `EitherAsync`. I assume you meant something like this:

```
private static EitherAsync<Error, HttpContent> FetchUriAsync(Uri uri) => 
    TryAsync(async () =>
        (await new HttpClient().GetAsync(uri)).Content
    ).ToEither();
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Actually I'm struggling a bit with language-ext. Can you recommend some learning-sources?